# Task return type

Tags: c#

I have following method

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Send()
    {    
       await doAsyncOperations();
       /*
        * some other code
       */
       return Ok();
    }

private Task doAsyncOperations()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                string query = @"INSERT STATEMENT";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
}
```

But for doAsyncOperations method I got error ***not all code paths return a value***, but this method is void type and I don't want to return any value.

When I change *Task doAsyncOperations* to *void doAsyncOperations* I cannot use await keyword. How I can call async method from api method?

Comment: `Private async void doAsyncOperations()`? Otherwise, you will need to return a task from the method

Comment: Show contents of that method

Comment: Did you mean to declare it as `private async Task doAsyncOperations()`?

Comment: @ChrisWatts `async void` cannot be awaited. it should be `async Task`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually doing anything asynchronous so change the return type of the method to `void` and do not use the `async/await` in your controller method. You should know when to use `async/await` but in a nutshell you use it when you want to free the thread when you are waiting for some type of I/O to complete like a database query or reading a file from disk (2 basic examples).

```
public IHttpActionResult Send()
{    
    doOperations();
    return Ok();
}

private void doOperations()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = @"INSERT STATEMENT";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

You could change your code and make the ADO.NET calls asynchronous like this.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Send()
{    
    await doOperationsAsync();
    return Ok();
}

private async Task doOperationsAsync()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        await con.OpenAsync();
        string query = @"INSERT STATEMENT";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The ADO interface has async methods that can be used.

Comment: @Romoku - I can only type so fast ;)